# Multiple user created modules from a directory not in PATH using just command window (Anaconda 3)

Tags: python

Up to this point I have organized my projects in such a way that everything I'm working on is in the same folder, so to play around/debug I have just launched Python from that folder like this:

```
C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Projects\MyShinyProject>Python
>>>
```

However, I want to start organizing things better. I have created some "Utilities" classes that I expect I'll use over and over again. So they should be in their own folder.

So now, say I have a Projects folder (in Windows) with lots of subfolders of things I have been working on:

```
Projects
    Sandbox
    Sandbox1
    Sandbox2
    MyUtilities
        __init__.py
        Utility1.py
    MyShinyProject
        __init__.py
        ImportantClass.py
```

I would like to be able to go into the command prompt and use classes/functions from both the MyUtilities folder and from the MyShinyProject folder. However, if I launch Python from inside MyShinyProject, I don't have access to MyUtilities (or vice versa). I've tried doing a relative import like this:

```
>>>import ..MyUtilities.Utility1
```

But that doesn't work:

```
import ..MyUtilities.Utility1
       ^
SyntaxError
```

If it matters: I don't use an IDE. I just use Notepad++ and the command prompt. Also, I added the `__init__.py` files to the folders because I read somewhere you're supposed to do that when you make modules, but I don't understand how to get all of this working correctly, or if I'm even close to doing it right.

I also tried adding my Projects folder to the PATH variable in the Windows environment table, but that doesn't seem to work. Even after adding it importing doesn't work, and when I do this:

```
import sys
for x in sys.path:
    print(x)
```

...the folder I added to PATH does not appear (I tried adding it to the beginning and the end).

How can I use several of my user created modules together using the command prompt to import them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `__init__.py` in your Projects folder, in the console you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Projects")
import Projects.MyUtilities.Utility1
```

Or if you want to add your desired directory permanently to the python path, you can append your directory to the value of the environment variable called PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Well I didn't have a PYTHONPATH variable so I created one, and it worked! Thanks. Is there any reason I should not have done it this way? Side effects/downsides...?

Comment: By the way: it worked even without an `__init__.py` in my Projects folder. Seems you only need `__init__.py` in each module folder. Is this what you meant?